# MySQL combine 2 tables in 1 than combine it with another one

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables (Titles and Episodes).

```
   Table Titles

   id |  title  |  type  | views
   ------------------------------
   1  |  Lucy   | movie  | 300
   2  |  Narcos | series | 2600
   3  | Ip Man  | movie  | 120
   4  |  Creed  | movie  | 460


   Table Episodes

   id |  title_id  |   title  |  episode | views
   ----------------------------------------------
   1  |      2     | episode1 |     1    | 100
   2  |      2     | episode2 |     2    | 260
   3  |      2     | episode3 |     3    | 96
   4  |      2     | episode4 |     4    | 210
```

Now i use this query to get most viewed episodes.

```
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, episodes.title_id, episodes.episode, episodes.views FROM titles, episodes WHERE titles.id = episodes.title_id ORDER BY episodes.views DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```

And i use this query for movies.

```
SELECT titles.id, titles.title, titles.views WHERE type = 'movie' ORDER BY titles.views DESC LIMIT 0, 16
```

I want to combine this two last queries into 1 temporary table to show most viewed movies and episodes.

```
   Temporary Table

   id |  title_id  |        title      |   views
   ----------------------------------------------
   1  |      4     |       Creed       |   460 
   2  |      1     |       Lucy        |   300  
   3  |      2     |  Narcos Episode 2 |   260  
   4  |      2     |  Narcos Episode 4 |   210
```

How can i do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: you can read about joins

Comment: Yes. See about joins. You can use an outer join in conjunction with COALESCE. And that's NOT the query you use for movies

Answer (score 0):

you can use view 
see this page to more information 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: At least you didn't do the guy's homework assignment for him. So "Read up on joins" is exactly the correct answer.

Comment: Answers should contain more than just a link. You should at least quote the most relevant sentences from the page you are linking to. [answer]

Answer (score 0):

I got it, thank you @sagi

```
  (SELECT titles.id as title_id, concat(titles.title,' ',episodes.title) as                          
  title,episodes.views as views
  FROM titles, episodes 
  WHERE titles.id = episodes.title_id and type = 'series'
  ORDER BY episodes.views DESC LIMIT 0, 16) 
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT titles.id, titles.title, titles.views as views
  FROM titles
  WHERE type = 'movie'
  ORDER BY titles.views DESC LIMIT 0, 16) ORDER BY views DESC
```